# Basic issue with variables

Tags: ruby

I feel like I'm missing something very, very fundamental, so, to avoid tearing out more hair, I come here to ask why p1, p1t and p1t2 are getting modified on with "hand = newgame.view p1". I don't even know why p1 is getting modified, so yeah I'm totally baffled here. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

```
# encoding: utf-8

class Cards

def view hand
    x = 0
    hand.each do |card|
        if card[0] == 's'
            card[0] = '♠'
        elsif card[0] == 'd'
            card[0] = '♦'
        elsif card[0] == 'h'
            card[0] = '♥'
        elsif card[0] == 'c'
            card[0] = '♣'
        else
            #nil
        end
        hand[x] = card
        x = x + 1
    end
    prettyhand = ''
    hand.each do |card|
        prettyhand = prettyhand + card[0] + card[1] + ' '
    end
    return prettyhand
end#view

end#Cards
###########

deck = 0
up = 0
p1 = 0
p2 = 0
newgame = Cards.new
p1 = [["c", "4"], ["s", "4"], ["d", "q"], ["c", "8"], ["s", "5"], ["s", "q"], ["h", "3"], ["c", "10"]]
    p1t = []
    p1t2 = []
    hand = ''
    p1.each do |card|
        p1t.push card
    end
    p1t.each do |card|
        p1t2.push card
    end
    p '----------------------------------'
    p 'fresh p1:'
    p p1
    p p1t
    p p1t2
    hand = newgame.view p1
    p 'unfresh p1:'#why is this changing??
    p p1
    p p1t
    p p1t2
    p '----------------------------------'
```

output:

```
"----------------------------------"
"fresh p1:"
[["c", "4"], ["s", "4"], ["d", "q"], ["c", "8"], ["s", "5"], ["s", "q"], ["h", "3"], ["c", "10"]]
[["c", "4"], ["s", "4"], ["d", "q"], ["c", "8"], ["s", "5"], ["s", "q"], ["h", "3"], ["c", "10"]]
[["c", "4"], ["s", "4"], ["d", "q"], ["c", "8"], ["s", "5"], ["s", "q"], ["h", "3"], ["c", "10"]]
"unfresh p1:"
[["♣", "4"], ["♠", "4"], ["♦", "q"], ["♣", "8"], ["♠", "5"], ["♠", "q"], ["♥", "3"], ["♣", "10"]]
[["♣", "4"], ["♠", "4"], ["♦", "q"], ["♣", "8"], ["♠", "5"], ["♠", "q"], ["♥", "3"], ["♣", "10"]]
[["♣", "4"], ["♠", "4"], ["♦", "q"], ["♣", "8"], ["♠", "5"], ["♠", "q"], ["♥", "3"], ["♣", "10"]]
"----------------------------------"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are passed by reference, not copied. Check out this snippet.

```
a1 = [[1], [2], [3]]
a2 = []

a2 << a1.first # push a reference to the array
a2 # => [[1]]


a1[0][0] += 1 # => 2
a1 # => [[2], [2], [3]] # a1 has changed
a2 # => [[2]] # a2 changed too!

# now push a copy of the array
a2 = [a1.first.dup] # => [[2]]

a1[0][0] += 1 # => 3
a1 # => [[3], [2], [3]] # a1 has changed
a2 # => [[2]] # a2 has not
```

Comment: In particular, note that this applies to method calls, as well.  Your Cards#view method therefore modifies its argument.

Comment: I think I understand! What, then, is the best solution here? Should I convert the arrays into strings to make copies of them? Thanks!

Comment: You can keep them as arrays, just make a copy before modifying them.  That's what the `dup` method does, as @SergioTulentsev demonstrated.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: Thanks - I was not aware of that function :>

Comment: @catbat: yes, it's a very important feature. Probably the most important :)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a method `view` which takes a parameter `hand` (BTW, parens are nice, not sure why you always omit them in your code, even in the method signature).  The `view` method modifies its argument `hand`.  You call it as

```
hand = newgame.view p1
```

This, `p1` is modified by the method `view`, and that's why it changes.

I'm also curious why you set `p1` to `0`... and then set it to an array of arrays.  There is no reason to do that. Also, try to use descriptive variable names, for yourself as well as others.

Comment: Merci - when you say 'signature', does this mean the return line?

Comment: @catbat: Sorry.  It means the name of the method and the arguments it takes (and, in a static language, the return type).  So `def view(hand)` is the method signature.

Comment: Got it. I usually use them and will definitely continue to use them in the future. edit: It looks kind of odd because it's just hastily been thrown together. Setting it to 0 wasn't done for any purposeful reason :>

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, your `view` method could be simplified a lot:

```
class Cards
  Suits = { 'c' => '♣', 'd' => '♦', 'h' => '♥', 's' => '♠' }

 def view(hand)
    hand.map do |suit, rank| [ Suits[suit], rank ] end
 end
end
```

This version doesn't modify anything, so avoids the issue.

Comment: That's very interesting I will need to do some reading on .map as I'm not very familiar with it but it appears to be a much simpler approach. Gracias!

Comment: map (also known as `collect`) is a good way to make a copy of an array with some changes. You supply a block of code that gets run on every element; the return value of the block becomes the replacement element in the copy. For instance, to increment every number in a list: `[1,2,3].map { |x| x+1 }`, which returns `[2,3,4]`.